# GitLab: Option to create branch from the issue is missing

Tags: gitlab

I am trying to create a branch linked from an issue on GitLab. The option to create a branch from the issue however is missing on this particular project. I have an access level of `Maintainer` on this project.

**The current project I'm working on:**

[image]

I have checked the other project I made a few months back on which I have exactly the same access level, the option that I'm looking for is there.

**My previous project (This is a different project btw, not the source of the fork)**

[image]

The difference being is that the current project I am working on is a forked version of the old repo so I could keep historical branches from the previous version of the project. I also imported the issues from the previous repo to the new one. I tried to create a new `test` issue but I still can't see the menu.

It seems like I configured something wrong, could you please help me identify why I cannot access this menu? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some digging, I found that this may be a current known issue on GitLab. It only happens on forked projects similar to [@VonC's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73075569/8331324) answer. However it doesn't show how to resolve the issue.

To resolve the issue you have to remove the project's **fork relationship** found on the `Settings > General > Advance`. If you forked the repo from another project, you should see the `Remove fork relationship` button there. This essentially removes the fork relationship of the project from the original repository. Once done, the `Create merge request` should pop-up immediately upon refreshing the page. Do note you need an `Owner` access to see the `Remove fork relationship` option.

For more details, please refer to this [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/20704) and this solution was from [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/20704#note_200377431).

Answer (score 1):

Check first if this is similar to [issue 39778](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/31612#note_220681924) which refers to [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/merge_requests/2808#note_3751987)

> I disable the button for projects which are forked.

The context in when it references (from a fork) issue from the original project.
No "Create merge request" in that case.